# Send dataset to a postgress database from HPPSystem - ECL

Tags: hpcc-ecl, hpcc

I need to send an uploaded dataset from a csv inside the ECL Watch of HPCCSystem.

I don't know where the ODBC driver is installed on the server, I downloaded a VM template that contains the HPCCSystem platform from the official site.
From the ECL IDE I create an .ecl document and when I insert the IMPORT ODBC line, it does not detect the odbc module. How can I do to be able to send the dataset information to the Postgres BD.
Thank you

I tried to insert the ODBC module but the platform does not detect it

Answer (score 0):

There was an ODBC driver in beta a few years back, but it looks like the project is no longer active. A good alternative to what you need to do is to Despray the file to the Landing Zone using the ECL Watch or the ECL Despray library function and from there you can download the file to a local location and import into Postgres.

Comment: ooof .. um without one how is someone suppose to get data into it?  like an OLE or something?

Comment: Any file on the HPCC cluster can be exported to the Landing Zone via the ECL Watch or by program control using the Standard Library Functions. Once external to the HPCC, you can download the file to your local machine and then import it into PostGres.